# Why can the a combination of an exponential and logarithmus function be used to create a powerlaw distribution

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, exponential-function

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063871/25282) a question on StackOverflow where a person wanted a randomized function that produces as many numbers between 0-10, 10-100 and 100-1000.

I offered the following function that does the job:

```
Math.floor(Math.exp(Math.random()*Math.log(maxmimum-minimum+1)))+minimum
```

In the comments, I was asked why this function works for the job and I can't come up with a good explanation. It's just obvious to me that it works.

Can someone provide a good explanation of why it works?

Comment: Your expression should end `* minimum` not `+ minimum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generate random numbers according to a particular distribution is to generate random numbers on $[0,1)$ and then use the inverse cumulative distribution function give the distribution.

You want your cumulative distribution function (before rounding to integers) to be of the form $a\log(x)+b$ between two values $m$ and $M$. Since $F(m)=0$ and $F(M)=1$, this gives $b=-a\log(m)$ and $a=\frac{1}{\log(M)-\log(m)}$, so $$F(x)=\frac{\log(x)-\log(m)}{\log(M)-\log(m)}$$ when $m\lt x \lt M$.  Its inverse is $$F^{-1}(y) = e^{y(\log(M)-\log(m))+\log(m)}=e^{y(\log(M)-\log(m))}m = m\left(\frac{M}{m}\right)^y$$

Now you can just plug your uniform random number $Y$ on $[0,1)$ into any of these expressions; you chose something close to $e^{y(\log(M)-\log(m))}m$.

Since you are then going to round down to an integer, you want $M$ equal to `maximum+1` and $m$ equal to `minimum` and that more or less gives your expression

Comment: But why does it turn uniform distribution to become this uniform in equal parts distribution? I look at the graph and f(x) goes almost straight up, which should act like uniform distribution so we should see more values in the larger ranges, but we actually see values in the smaller ranges as well.

Comment: @shinzou In $F^{-1}(y)$, you have $y$ taking values form $0$ to $1$, so it produces all values between $m$ and $M$.  If you plot $F^{-1}(y)$ on a logarithmic scale, that is to say $\log\left(F^{-1}(y)\right)$ against $y$, you get a straight line.  So if $y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$, then you are as likely to get a value for $F^{-1}(y)$ between $1$ and $10$ as you are to get a value between $100$ and $1000$, which is what was originally requested (before rounding to integers)